# how to associate value with specific form in formset in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I want associate a related objected to corresponding forms in a formset.  So far I have:

```
ModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(Notification, form=NotificationsForm, extra=5)

    generic_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Department)
    queryset = Notification.objects.filter(notificationrelation__content_type_id=generic_type.id)
    formset = ModelFormSet(queryset=queryset)

    for notification in formset.get_queryset():
        relation = NotificationRelation.objects.get(notification=notification)
        department = Department.objects.get(pk=relation.object_id)
```

My models look like the following:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Notification Name', max_length=128)

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Department Name', max_length=128)

class NotificationRelation(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    notification = models.ForeignKey(Notification)
```

I want to relate the department on the last line with the related notification in the formset.

Something like:

```
for form in formset:
     if something:
         form.department = department
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You can't just use an inline_formset, or am I missing something?

Comment: that would work if the relation was a foreign key, but the notifications and departments use a generic foreign key.  The object_id in the relation object is not explicitly tied to the department id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to use the inline form but multiple forms instead.